# Intermittent error when connecting to Apache LDAP Server from azure app

Tags: azure, ldap

I'm facing an issue with my ASP.NET Core Web API, where I connect to Apache LDAP for fetching and updating user information, as well as cloning the connection. I'm using the Novell LDAP C# library with standard code from their documentation.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// C# Library namespace
using Novell.Directory.Ldap;

// Creating an LdapConnection instance LdapConnection 
ldapConn= new LdapConnection();

//Connect function will create a socket connection to the server
ldapConn.Connect(ldapHost,ldapPort);

//Bind function will bind the user object Credentials to the server
ldapConn.Bind(userDN,userPasswd);
```

However, I encounter the following error in my application logs:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.AsyncExtensions.WaitAndUnwrap(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Int32 semaphoreId)", Category: "Error", Name: "Unhandled Exception", EventType: Error, Id: 3000, Message: "Connect Error", ActivityId: "0000000-0000-f900-b63f-84710c7967bb", TimeStamp: 11/22/2023 17:43:02, ProcessId: 7376, LocalIpAddress: "REDACTED.1.95:443", RemoteIpAddress: "REDACTED.213" }
2023-11-22T17:43:02.8087664+00:00 [FTL] (IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware) Unhandled exception: "Connect Error"
LdapException: Unable to connect to server REDACTED.186:10389 (91) Connect Error
```

This error occurs intermittently (about 4-5 times a day) on my Azure App Service. Notably, there are no errors or packet loss reported on the Azure firewall. I've also checked the LDAP logs, and they indicate a successful bind operation at the same time of the error on the Azure side.

```
[07:11:30] DEBUG [org.apache.directory.server.OPERATION_LOG] - << BindOperation successful
[07:11:30] DEBUG [org.apache.directory.server.OPERATION_TIME] - Bind operation took 142797 ns
```

I'm looking for guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.